# Are marcos of myproject.vcxproj available in cake build?

Tags: cakebuild

Is it possible to use macros like $(OutDir) and $(ProjectName) in cake build?

I want to do further process on the output file of a VC++ project.

For example, I want to protect the binary by calling 'upx myproject.exe', but don't want to hard code the exe name.

I know this could be done in Post-Event of my VC++ project, just want to know if there is way doing same in cake-build.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of Project Parsers in Cake, which allow you to access things like output file name, and references, etc.  This works well for *.csproj and *.vbproj files,  but I am not sure if this will work for the project type you are using.

http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Solution.Project/ProjectAliases/A553D651

If this doesn't work, then you may have to look at creating something similar specifically for this project type.

Comment: Got 'Error: Failed to parse project properties'.

Comment: ParseSolution works and returns a collection of projects, but I don't want to iterate them to find the particular one.

Comment: As I mentioned, the built in ParseProject was designed to work with csproj and vbproj files, so there was no guarantee that it would work with this project type.  You may have to implement something similar to what is done specifically for this project type.